# Rails page caching with Apache and capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

The following post explains about the page caching in rails with Nginx.

http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/1/30/segregated-page-cache-storage

I like to implement this solution with my app but on Apache.
So, the main block/route is

```
  if (-f $request_filename) { 
    break; 
  }
    if (-f /cache$request_filename) { 
    rewrite (.*) /cache$1 break;
    break; 
  }

  if (-f /cache$request_filename.html) { 
    rewrite (.*) /cache$1.html break;
    break; 
  }
```

What could be the Apache equivalent for the above Nginx related code??

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/$ /cache/index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /cache$1.html [QSA]
```

The 2nd line checks if the cached file exists before doing the redirect, otherwise it would let the request go through to Rails.